# A portion of a page disappears. What happens?

Tags: firefox, autohotkey, webpage, emoji

One day I visit https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/campaign-url-builder and the portion in red rectangle of that page disappears. I open the browser in addons disabled mode (which means there is no adblock and script running) and it still persists. But in private browsing it comes back again.

It seems that it's because of using hotstring containing emoji in the fields that make them disappeared. Do you know how to check?

[image]

Comment: No repro on Windows 7 Home Premium 64 bit, Firefox 81.0

Comment: @FedonKadifeli hmm, yes it works. I don't know why cookies have anything to do with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing cookies works. I don't know why cookies have anything to do with this